# Reading next lines from txt file in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, input

I have created the codes down below where it reads from a data.txt file and split each character into the array. Right now it reads the first line from the data.txt only. How can I make it loop and read the next line?

Can someone show me what needs to be added?

Contents of data.txt file

```
 O7550x
 N9300x
 H51200
```

This is my existing code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("Product code: ");
char a[6];
int i=0;


FILE *fptr;
fptr=fopen("data.txt", "r");
   
while((a[i++]=getc(fptr)) != '\n' && i < 6);

if(a[0] >= 'A' && a[0] <= 'Z')
{
if (a[0]=='O')
{
    printf("State: Ohio");
}
else if (a[0]=='I'||a[0]=='H')
{
    printf("State: Hawaii");
}
else if (a[0]=='N')
{
    printf("State: New York");
}
else
{
    printf("State: Unknown");
}
    printf("\n");
if (a[1]=='5')
{
    printf("Stores: Five");
}
else if (a[1]=='7')
{
    printf("Stores: Seven");
}
else if (a[1]=='9')
{
    printf("Stores: Nine");
}
else
{
   printf("Stores: Unknown");
}
   printf("\n");
if (a[2]=='3'&&a[3]=='0'&&a[4]=='0')
{
    printf("Inventory: 300 units");
}
else if (a[2]=='5'&&a[3]=='5'&&a[4]=='0')
{
    printf("Inventory: 500 units");
}
else if (a[2]=='1'&&a[3]=='2'&&a[4]=='0'&&a[5]=='0')
{
    printf("Inventory: 1200 units");

}
else
{
   printf("Inventory: Unknown");
}

}
else
   printf("Invalid code");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note, code like `if (a[1]=='5')` occurs without checking that `i`, in fact, is at least 2. IMO, never trust that input is well formed.  Instead test it.

Comment: Please, for pity's sake, indent your code in an orthodox style!

Comment: You need to change the call to `getchar()` to `getc(fptr)` — and then you're done (apart from remembering to close the file stream you opened when you've finished reading).  An alternative is to use [`freopen()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.4) with `stdin` as the third parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is the thing you want to do, but here is the code below that does both command-line input and txt file read. However, you cannot loop through all elements with this code. For that purpose, you need to read the number of lines and dynamically allocate memory and store each line in the second dimension of the dynamically created array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printProductCode(char*);
int numberOfLines(FILE*);
void display_array(char**, int, int);

int main()
{
    int flag, sizeOfFile = 0, readFrom = 0;
    char **b;
    char a[6];
    int i=0;
    FILE *fptr;

    do {
        flag = 1;
        printf("Which way you will enter the product code? (Command-Line: 1), (File: 2) ");
        scanf("%d",&readFrom);

        if(readFrom == 1) {
            printf("Product code: ");
            getchar();
            while((a[i++]=getchar()) != '\n' && i < 6);
        } else if(readFrom == 2) {
            int j = 0;
            fptr=fopen("data.txt", "r");

            sizeOfFile = numberOfLines(fptr);
            b = (char**)malloc(sizeOfFile * sizeof(char*));

            for (int i = 0;i < sizeOfFile;i++) {
                b[i] = (char*)malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
            }

            while(fscanf(fptr, "%s", b[j++]) != EOF);
        } else {
            printf("Please enter valid input!");
            flag = 0;
        }
    } while(flag == 0);

    if (readFrom == 1) {
        printProductCode(a);
    }
    else if(readFrom == 2){
        for(int i = 0;i < sizeOfFile;i++) {
            printProductCode(b[i]);
        }

        //Freeing could done with a different if statement because
        //we may want to use b in the following steps, but for
        //simplicity I freed the memory here for now on.
        for(int i=0;i<sizeOfFile;i++) {
            free(b[i]);
        }
        free(b);
    }



    return 0;
}

void printProductCode(char* a) {
    if(a[0] >= 'A' && a[0] <= 'Z')
    {
        if (a[0]=='O')
        {
            printf("State: Ohio");
        }
        else if (a[0]=='I'||a[0]=='H')
        {
            printf("State: Hawaii");
        }
        else if (a[0]=='N')
        {
            printf("State: New York");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("State: Unknown");
        }
        printf("\n");
        if (a[1]=='5')
        {
            printf("Stores: Five");
        }
        else if (a[1]=='7')
        {
            printf("Stores: Seven");
        }
        else if (a[1]=='9')
        {
            printf("Stores: Nine");
        }
        else
        {
           printf("Stores: Unknown");
        }
        printf("\n");
        if (a[2]=='3'&&a[3]=='0'&&a[4]=='0')
        {
            printf("Inventory: 300 units");
        }
        else if (a[2]=='5'&&a[3]=='5'&&a[4]=='0')
        {
            printf("Inventory: 500 units");
        }
        else if (a[2]=='1'&&a[3]=='2'&&a[4]=='0'&&a[5]=='0')
        {
            printf("Inventory: 1200 units");

        }
        else
        {
           printf("Inventory: Unknown");
        }
    }
    else
       printf("Invalid code");
    printf("\n\n");
}

int numberOfLines(FILE* fp) {
    int counter = 0;
    char c = fgetc(fp);
    while(c != EOF) {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (c == '\n'){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    rewind(fp);
    return (counter + 1);
}

void display_array(char** arr, int r, int c) {
    for(int i = 0;i<r;i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j < c;j++) {
            printf("%c", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Also, here is the text file you need to provide for this code.

```
O7550x
N9300x
H51200
```

Good luck!

I edited the code in a way that it can read all lines and print the results.

Comment: It reads only the first line of the data.txt file. Can it be modified to read all ? Then display the results for each code.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in my answer, you need to create a 2 D dynamic array that has a size of lines in the text file for the first dimension, and the second dimension can be created as simply 6 if you are sure that the text file always holds 6 characters for each line, and then do the loop using the fscanf line.

Comment: I edited the code the way you wanted.

Comment: Can you show me how to print the product code in the output as well? Like "Product Code: H51200" before the State: and Stores: lines.

Comment: Sure, add this code `printf("Product Code: %s\n",a);` to the beginning of the printProductCode. Since we have codes stored at character array a, we can simply print the value of the array a.